# Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell XPS 9360 freezes

Tags: boot, 18.04, dell, freeze, xps

I've been using ubuntu 18.04 on my [Dell XPS 9360](https://www.dell.com/support/search/us/en/04#q=XPS%209360&sort=relevancy&f:iuxType=[Manuals%20%26%20Documentation]&f:langFacet=[en]) for about a month. Today it started to freeze (except for the mouse) while I was using it, so I had to restart it using the physical button.

For my surprise it didn't boot when I restarted, it remained on the Dell logo screen without allowing me even to access the BIOS/firmware. After a couple restarts it eventually started Ubuntu (I don't use dual boot).

I faced the same problem about 5 times during the rest of the day, not always having to restart several times for the system to boot properly. In the cases the laptop froze after a short time, not even 10 minutes.

The hardware diagnostic said that everything is fine, which was as weird given that this randomness made me think it was a hardware problem.

Ps: I've seen some people with a similar problem, but related to GPU, which is not my case since my laptop has integrated Intel graphics

Edit 1:

It eventually stopped to boot Ubuntu, getting stuck on the Dell logo screen. I managed to get into bios (it took more than 3 minutes of loading, which was strange) and it pointed to a hard drive error ("Hard drive not installed").

I removed the SSD from the booting sequence, but the problem of taking to long to enter the bios remained.

I manage to use a USB Stick with Manjaro on it, after a long time again (about 3-5 minutes) it booted the system on the flash drive. The Manjaro on the flash drive is working normally (I'm actually using it right now) and GParted wasn't able to find my SSD.

Does anybody has any idea of why the dell screen is taking so long to go to the bios or to boot the system on the flash drive? Is it just a problem on my SSD or maybe also something else?

Comment: _Gustavo Sutter_, memory diagnostics overlook a lot of errors. May I suggest you remove and then reinsert your memory modules?

Comment: It may be a failing hard drive or loose RAM.

Comment: You mention it freezing, but not the mouse?  Can you use [magic] sysreq keys to restart the system?  ie. Alt+Sysrq+REISUB (look up https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=617349 or search "magic sysrq" [using phone etc] and you'll find the wikipedia article which is also a good reminder of the keystrokes)  If these work the base system is good (as reflected by mouse) & just desktop isn't - if these don't work; it could be you have keyboard [hardware] issues you need to explore

Comment: Its RAM is integrated on the motherboard and it has a SSD. And I tried the sysreq keys and it did not work

Comment: Apparently it is something to do with the SSD, but I'm not sure what exactly